# Proving Gaussian log-Sobolev inequality from Euclidean version

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

I'm reading some notes which say we can prove the Gaussian logarithmic Sobolev inequality
$$ \int f^2\log f^2 d\mu \leq 2 \int |\nabla f|^2d\mu $$
for $d\mu(x) = e^{-|x|^2/2}dx/(2\pi)^{n/2}$ and $\int f^2d\mu = 1$ by starting from the Euclidean logarithmic Sobolev inequality
$$ \int f^2\log f^2dx \leq \frac{n}{2}\log\left(\frac{2}{n\pi e}\int |\nabla f|^2dx\right) $$
for $dx$ Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ and $\int f^2dx = 1$.

The proof is done by substituting $fe^{-|x|^2/4}$ but I'm not sure what happens to the remaining term. Here is what I see when I make the substitution into the Euclidean LSI:

$$ \int f^2\log(f^2e^{-|x|^2/2}) e^{-|x|^2/2}dx = \int f^2\log f^2d\mu + \int f^2\log(e^{-|x|^2/2}) d\mu $$ appears on the left hand side so the first term is what we want but the second term is $-\frac{1}{2} \int f^2|x|^2 d\mu$.

Then on the right hand side presumably we can only use the inequality $|\nabla(fg)|^2 \leq 2f^2|\nabla g|^2 + 2g^2|\nabla f|^2$ to simplify things in which case we get

$$ \frac{n}{2}\log\left(\frac{4}{n\pi e}\left(\int |\nabla f|^2 d\mu + \frac{1}{4} \int f^2|x|^2 d\mu\right)\right) $$
since $|\nabla e^{-|x|^2/4}|^2 = |-\frac{x}{2}e^{-|x|^2/4}|^2 = \frac{1}{4}|x|^2e^{-|x|^2/2}$.

But I don't see how this simplifies to/is controlled by $\int |\nabla f|^2 d\mu$. Is there something else going on? Somehow I have two unwanted terms on the right hand side and a log. (I know $\log x \leq x$ but I can only guess something stronger must be happening otherwise we would just leave $\log$ there.)

Comment: *Hint:* Use Plancherel's theorem and properties of the Fourier transform on the second integral in the log.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - so it seems to me the second integral is $||fxe^{-x^2/4}||_{L^2}^2$ and by Plancherel's this should be equal to the squared $L^2$-norm of the Fourier transform of $fxe^{-x^2/4}$. I have a rough idea of the details but I'm still not entirely sure - $\hat{fx}$ should be $\nabla f$ to me (even though $\hat{f}x = \hat{\nabla f}$) I think, and the FT of a gaussian is a gaussian. But the FT of a product is a convolution and all I can think of is using Young's inequality. But then I lose the gaussian measure in the process. Is there a better approach or is this okay so far?